# Remove layout from PowerPoint slide in c# using OpenXml

Tags: c#, powerpoint, openxml, openxml-sdk

I'm using DocumentFormat.OpenXml package to manipulate with PowerPoint slides. What I need is for specific slide to remove its layout as I will get a blank slide(without shapes and templates on it).  I managed to remove all shaped from the slide. Also, I tried to remove the relationship to the current layout, but what layout should I add (how to achieve to have an empty slide)? Also, should I remove relationship with slideMaster?

[Image of the actual slide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hulRt.jpg)

[Image of the slide I need to get (empty slide)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lYrjX.png)

Looking for guidance.

Thanks, Aleksandra

Comment: So you just need a blank slide?

Comment: Post some code to show us what you tried